# Do exist constant curvature manifolds (hyperbolic or elliptic) with torsion?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I would say no. Because a constant curvature manifold is symmetric. Any 2 dimensional subspace should be like a hyperboloid or a sphere. These objects do not have torsion.

Comment: What do you mean by torsion? The word has many meanings in differential geometry. If you allow torsion in the connection, then the manifold is certainly not a symmetric space with that connection.

Comment: What do you mean by a 2 dimensional subspace? You can't mean any arbitrary submanifold, but you haven't assumed the existence of any totally geodesic surfaces.

Comment: I should be more accurate with words:

1. I meant a manifold with a non Levi-Civita connection, ie the non-vanishing torsion tensor (two form)

2. The right word for a 2d subspace is the sectional curvature (two-dimensional tangent plane). 

How do you see that if I allow the torsion in the connection then the curvature is not a constant? This is precisely my question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_curvature

Comment: The curvature can be a constant, even zero, for example every Lie group admits a left invariant flat connection, but with torsion.

Comment: The notion of sectional curvature is not defined using only a connection; a connection has a curvature, but to have sectional curvature, you need a metric too. Are you thinking of a manifold with both a Riemannian metric and an affine connection with nonzero torsion, so that the sectional curvature of the affine connection, as calculated using the metric, is constant? That seems like a lot of data.

Comment: A manifold is endowed with a metric g, and a connection D which is compatible with the metric, ie D g = 0. 
As you said a Lie group is a good example. So saying that a manifold has a constant curvature does not imply it is torsion-less.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should consider the following example:

Let $M^3=\mathrm{SU}(2)\simeq S^3$ endowed with its biïnvariant metric $g$ (unique up to a constant multiple, let's fix this by requiring that the $g$ has constant sectional curvature equal to $1$).  Now consider the unique connection $\nabla$ for which the left-invariant vector fields on $SU(2)$ are parallel.  This connection is compatible with the biïnvariant metric and it has torsion, since $T(X,Y) = -[X,Y]\not=0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are linearly independent left-invariant vector fields.  This metric has the same geodesics as the Levi-Civita connection, and every $2$-plane has sectional-curvature $1$.

The symmetry group of $(M^3,g,\nabla)$ is $\mathrm{SO}(4)$, the maximum possible. So this is an example of a constant curvature manifold with torsion.

As É. Cartan and J. A. Schouten showed in 1926 (*On Riemannian geometries admitting an absolute parallelism*), this example generalizes to biïnvariant metrics on compact simple Lie groups endowed with the unique connection for which the left-invariant vector fields are parallel, though they no long actually have constant sectional curvature.

However, they also show in that paper that there is a connection $\nabla$ on the $7$-sphere $S^7$ of unit octonions that is flat, compatible with the natural metric of constant curvature on $S^7$, and invariant under the group $\mathrm{Spin}(7)\subset\mathrm{SO}(8)$.  Because $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$ acts transitively on $3$-planes in $\mathbb{O}\simeq\mathbb{R}^8$, it follows that this geometry $(S^7, g,\nabla)$ also has constant curvature.